# Beautiful Soup vs. lxml: Is Beautiful Soup not very robust or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, lxml

It seems that Beautiful Soup is missing a lot of stuff although I am using the `lxml` parser. Let's say I want to get the 401 (soccer) player names from the following website in Beautiful Soup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.dreamteamfc.com/statistics/form-guide/all'
r  = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

name_list = []

for td in soup.findAll("td", { "class" : "tabName" }):
    name = td.text.strip()
    if name:
        name_list.append(name)

print(len(name_list))
print(name_list[-1])
```

Output:

```
88
Santon, Davide
```

---

Now, the same thing using the `lxml` library:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'https://www.dreamteamfc.com/statistics/form-guide/all'

r = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(r.text)

name_list = []

names = tree.xpath('//td[@class="tabName"]/text()')
for name in names:
    name = name.strip()
    if name:
        name_list.append(name)

print(len(name_list))
print(name_list[-1])
```

Output:

```
401
Santon, Davide
```

In general, I like Beautiful Soup, is there any good way to make this work properly?

Comment: What version of beautifulsoup are you using? I just ran your code and got: `401
O'Brien, Joey`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sounds good, hopefully it's just a version issue. I am using `4.3.2` in Python 3.4

Comment: Just tried it in Python 2.7.9, and I get `201
Figueroa, Maynor`

Comment: Okay, I guess the problem is solved by using the `html5lib` parser. However, I am still curious why the lxml parser in Beautiful Soup doesn't work similarly "well" as the lxml module does

Comment: So you never got the correct answer using `bs4` + `lxml`? Something sounds fishy if that's the case because I did a fresh install of bs4 `4.2.1` under Ubuntu and ran it as expected under Python `2.7.6`

Comment: No, the `lxml` in  `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')` using Python 2.7 and 3.4 doesn't work correctly. However, `'html.parser'` and `'html5lib'` does. I can totally live with that now that I figured it out! Shall I delete this question or do you think it might be worthwhile for other people who might have similar issues?